# How to get jQuery countdown plugin to work

Tags: jquery, plugins, countdown, elapsedtime

I am using the [jQuery countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) and some how i just can't get it to work. the documentation on the plugin is not that helpful. I got to implement the basic/minimal version but after that I'm catching my tail to figure out the plugin.

I'm trying to create two things:

1. A time elapsed counter (count-up timer) which starts from  0hr 0min 0sec
2. A count down Timer  (example from 1hr 30min 0sec) to 0hr 0min 0sec

Answer (score 2):

I tried the basic countdown and it works.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
    @import "css/jquery.countdown.css";

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var austDay = new Date();
            austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
            $('#CountDown').countdown({ until: austDay });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="CountDown">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thats the basic countdown I have already tried implementing that one and got it to work it's when I try doing others that I can't get it to work.